# JQuery comand not retrieving all child elements properties, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some JQuery that selects one of the navigation links—based on the page that I'm on—and then moves it to the top of the list. That is working fine. The problem is that I want to make an if statement that will check if the user is on a page not in the nav links. If the if statement is true, it will prepend a 404 nav link in the list (but this prepend part is working fine and so it's kind of irreverent).

This is the HTML of my navigation bar:

```
<nav>
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="skillsets.php">Skillsets</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the JQuery I'm using:

```
var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ul = $('nav > ul'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        href = li.find('a[href*="'+page+'"]');
    //move element to top
    ul.prepend(href.parent());
    if(page != li.children('a').attr('href') && page != ""){
        ul.prepend("<li><a href='404NotFound.php'>404</a></li>");
    }
});
```

As you can see, the if statement is supposed to check if my page variable is not equal to the link values contained within the list elements and that the page variable isn't blank. The problem with this is that `li.children('a').attr('href')` only returns the first nav link: index.php, and none of the others. So if I'm on any page other than my home page, the if statement is returned as true.

I'm very open to suggestions, like if an if statement isn't the best way to do what I'm trying to do i.e. if there were some way to check if `ul.prepend(href.parent());` actually executed. Thanks!

Update:

I'll explain what I'm asking a little better here. I have a server at ndi.grn.cc/ (can't exactly demonstrate this on JSFiddle). When someone goes to ndi.grn.cc/, ndi.grn.cc/index.php, ndi.grn.cc/skillsets.php, ndi.grn.cc/gallery.php, ndi.grn.cc/about.php, or ndi.grn.cc/contact.php I don't want the if statement to return true (and then making the 404 link not be created and prepended) though I do want the respective nav links to be prepended (they're being prepended so don't worry about that). I want the 404 link to be added when someone goes to ndi.grn.cc/asdkjgkj, or simply misspells something and goes to ndi.grn.cc/skilsets.php. So basically I want `li.children('a').attr('href')` to get not just: index.php, but also skillsets.php, gallery.php, about.php, and contact.php

If you go to my website you will see that this adding of the 404 link works, but too often. The only time the 404 link won't be added is when you're on ndi.grn.cc/ or ndi.grn.cc/index.php. You will also notice that these functions make my nav bar kind of confusing and ugly. This is because I have this code set up so it will only execute on my mobile website which is going to have an accordion nav bar. For simplicities sake (so you guys don't have to test this site on your iDevices or Androids) I made it so this code also executes on my regular site. You may also notice that the skillsest.php and gallery.php pages don't exist yet. This website is a very big work in progress; I have a lot to add and improve upon.

By the way, var page will return "" if you're on ndi.grn.cc/, "contact.php" if you're on ndi.grn.cc/contact.php or even if you're on ndi.grn.cc/contact.php?mail=sent. Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Remove <icon> before Gallery.

Comment: @JonasT That didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you're calling `attr`. `attr` will only match against the first matched element.

[From jQuery (attr):](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute **for the first element in the set of matched elements** or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

What that means is you'll want to update your code to look something like this:

```
li.children('a').each(function(){ /* do something with $(this).attr() */ })
```

Good luck!

Edit: Here's a fiddle demonstrating `each` (where I change the link with 'gif' to google.com)

http://jsfiddle.net/Qkxp7/

Comment: I put this into my `$(document).ready(function(){`: `li.children('a').each(function(){
  var nav_links = $(this).attr('href');
 })` and it broke my code.

Comment: Does your code look something like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9173400fc74f73fb22dd

Comment: Also, does it have the colon? "function(){: li.children" (after the "{")

Comment: No, it doesn't look like that, should it. And no it doesn't have the colon.

Comment: Yikes, It shouldn't actually. Let me throw a fiddle together!

Comment: Okay, now Dreamweaver tells me that this last part of my `$(document).ready(function(){` which is this: `});` has a syntax error.

Comment: Could you post the entire snippet of code as a gist? (http://gist.github.com) - I'll lint it for errors and see if anything stands out!

Comment: Never mind, I was missing an end bracket in the code. You'll see that I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: I've just noticed that now the 404 link never gets added (prepended). I will not unmark your answer as correct, but I've posted my full code as a gist at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a6f7889f88a72c5225d and I was wondering if you could check it out. You'll notice that I've changed `if (page != this.attr('href')) {` to `if (page == this.attr('href')) {` but either way they're not working, and I believe that what I've changed it to is correct anyways.

Comment: Hey LarryK, I think it's a JS error. Your `page == this` should be `page == $(this)` - Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fA6Np/ Thanks for marking it as an answer, btw!

Comment: Thanks but I just tried that just a few seconds ago actually; as I saw it in the jQuery API Documentation, but it didn't do anything. Before you ask, yes I tried clearing my cache.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time again. As it turns out, I had added an alert: `alert(this.attr('href'));` in the loop, that was for some reason was breaking it.